# Found com.jalil.naby.Card, required 'Card'

Tags: android, validation, payment, credit-card

Right now I'm implementing a credit card service like "Stripe", here is my function addCard. At the end of it, "openpay.createCard(***card***, this);", card has an error that says: "**Wrong 1st argument type.Found com.jalil.naby.Card, required 'Card'**" but I don't understand what does it mean. It is code that OpenPay (Stripe like service) gave as an example. It just doesn't work on my project but it does on theirs.

```
private void addCard() {
    Openpay openpay = ((OpenPayAppExample) this.getApplication()).getOpenpay();
    Card card = new Card();
    boolean isValid = true;

    final EditText holderNameEt = ((EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.nombre));
    final String holderName = holderNameEt.getText().toString();
    card.holderName(holderName);
    if (!CardValidator.validateHolderName(holderName)) {
        holderNameEt.setError(this.getString(R.string.invalid_holder_name));
        isValid = false;
    }

    final EditText cardNumberEt = ((EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.noTarjeta));
    final String cardNumber = cardNumberEt.getText().toString();
    card.cardNumber(cardNumber);
    if (!CardValidator.validateNumber(cardNumber)) {
        cardNumberEt.setError(this.getString(R.string.invalid_card_number));
        isValid = false;
    }

    EditText cvv2Et = ((EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.cvv));
    String cvv = cvv2Et.getText().toString();
    card.cvv2(cvv);
    if (!CardValidator.validateCVV(cvv, cardNumber)) {
        cvv2Et.setError(this.getString(R.string.invalid_cvv));
        isValid = false;
    }

    EditText yearE = ((EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.anio));

    EditText monthE = ((EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.mes));

    String yearS = yearE.getText().toString();
    int year = Integer.parseInt(yearS);

    String monthS = monthE.getText().toString();
    int month = Integer.parseInt(monthS);

    if (!CardValidator.validateExpiryDate(month, year)) {
        DialogFragment fragment = MessageDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.error,
                this.getString(R.string.invalid_expire_date));
        fragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "Error");
        isValid = false;
    }

    card.expirationMonth(month);
    card.expirationYear(year);

    if (isValid) {
        this.progressFragment.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "progress");
        openpay.createCard(card, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: If I'm looking at the correct example, it appears that the `Card` class should be `mx.openpay.android.model.Card`. It looks like you've created your own `Card` class – `com.jalil.naby.Card` – which, if you do indeed need that class, you should rename to something else to prevent confusion. Add, or change, the import statement in that `Activity` – `import mx.openpay.android.model.Card;`.

Comment: Thanks, I just copied to my project, didn't think it would be an issue.

Comment: Nah, you wouldn't copy anything directly from `openpay-android`. Those classes will be in the library you add to your project.